# Using Swift2.0 pods in Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, macos, osx-yosemite

I have a Mac with **`OSX Yosemite`** installed on it. Due to some reasons I am not able to update it to `El Capitan`. Thus I am stucked with `XCode 6.4` to develop apps for iOS.

I am using CocoaPods to work on my apps. Most of the pods which I want to use have been updated to work with `Swift 2.0` and `XCode 7+`. Is there any way I can use those pods to work on `XCode 6.4 /Swift 1.2`

**Note:**
For those who are suggesting me to upgrade giving various reasons, I am already aware of them. I should not use Swift 1.2, but that's the limitation, hence the question. I am not able to upgrade because I don't have authorisation to do that. Most of our apps needs to be tested on iOS7 too, which has no support in El Capitan. Now don't suggest me to upgrade to iOS9. I can't because these are enterprise apps and that is not my decision.

Comment: I am interested in Alamofire mostly, but a generic steps is welcome.

Comment: If upgrading to `El Capitan` is whats blocking you, I would suggest trying to find a fix for that, rather than ignoring it and trying to work around it

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin please see the updated question.

Comment: well then I don't understand the question. If the issue is that the libraries are  now updated to swift 2 and your using 1.2 ... use the last version of the libraries before they were updated.

Comment: You can use the specific version or commit of pod which supports your OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict your pod file pods to fetch specific versions of libraries which support swift 1.2. Read release notes for each library you have in your pod file to find out specific version which works with swift 1.2.

This is how you can restrict pod library to specific version: `pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.1.0'`

**But I would strongly recommend to find a way to update Xcode to latest release version. Xcode 7 has lots of improvements and bug fixes. You will enjoy using it.**

Answer (score 1):

**XCode 7 Runs on Yosemite OSX 10.10.4 or later**

**Swift 3.0 is about to be released. Beta released on 13 in WWDC 16.**
You should not use Swift 1.2 because Swift 2.2 has been released and there a lot of depreciations in Swift 1.2 and then 2.0 as well. Now Swift 3.0 Beta has also released on June 13 and there will be still changes in that as well. You should at least upgrade to 2.2. For XCode 7. Upgrade OSX Yosemite to 10.10.4 and XCode 7 will be installable. I've been using it on my 10.10.5 and it worked perfectly.